# Is it possible to have a single step definition to handle the cases mentioned below from `a to d`

Tags: cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

In our BDD automation framework, we are using Cypress Cucumber pre-processor library. We are planning to write a generic step definition for the cases below. Is it possible to have a single step definition to handle the cases mentioned below from `a to d`.
Right now I am planning to handle the cases in two step definitions, can we make it more generic, ie to have all in a single step definition  ?

```
a) Then I "should not" see the value "Some_Value" in the "Reports_Logs" table 
b) Then I "should" see the value "Some_Value" in the "Reports_Logs" table

c) Then I "should not" see the value in the "Users_Main" table ( in this case, I will read the value from the local storage )
d) Then I "should" see the value in the "Users_Main" table ( in this case, I will read the value from the local storage )
```

`step defintion:`

/* This generic function is used to verify all table td value assertions inside */

```
Then('I {string} see the value {string} in the {string} table', (checkCase, value, tableDatacy) => {
  if(checkCase === "should"){
    cy.get(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}]`).find('tbody').find('tr').each(($tr) => {
      cy.wrap($tr).find('td').each(($td) => {
        const textName = Cypress.$($td).text();
        switch (value) {
          case textName.trim():
            console.log("Condition got matched ...!!! " + textName.trim());
            cy.wrap($tr).find('td').contains(textName.trim()).should('be.visible');
            break;
        }
      });
    });
  } else if (checkCase === "should not") {
     // rest of the check with this condition..
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your steps C and D should check for a value and it would be more meaningful for the readers if you exactly specify what values should or should not be there, similar to A and B.

So if you re-write your steps C and D as shown here:

> c) Then I "should not" see the value "Some_Value" in the "Users_Main"
> table
> d) Then I "should" see the value "Some_Value" in the
> "Users_Main" table

Then you need to change your step definition to check for "Users_Main" table and can read from the local storage.

This way you can just have one step and cover all the 4 steps that you have mentioned and is better way of defining steps, as you are exactly checking what values should/should not be there.

Comment: Agree with Jerome, in any case c & d will not match the `Then()` because they lack the required number of parameters (value is missing). Therefore, you will need at least two steps definitions.

Comment: In step C and D I am unable to provide ‘Some_Value’ from feature file, as it creating unique value each time. Eg: Customer_dTghed23BZv. So while creating the value I am saving in localStorage and then reading from localStorage to assert them in table.

Comment: After creating and saving the unique value each time. I am storing them in localStorage and retrieving them in same scenario or next scenario for editing or asserting them in table. So I can't have them as a third parameter from feature file.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in the step can be improved.

`Should` condition

```js
cy.get(`[data-cy="${tableId}"] tbody td`)
  .filter(`:contains(${value})`)
  .should('be.visible')
  .log(`Success: "${value}" is in the table`)
```

`Should not` condition

```js
cy.get(`[data-cy="${tableId}"] tbody td`).then($cells => {
  const $matchingCells = $cells.filter(`:contains(${value})`)
  if ($matchingCells.length) {
    throw `Failed: "${value}" is in the table but should not be`
  } else {
    cy.log(`Success: "${value}" is not in the table`)
  }
})
```